# How to create Image in Timer method?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

For example. I have some Timer and i'm initializing it in my Window constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CheckTImer = new Timer(3000);
    CheckTimer.Elapsed += CheckTimer_Elapsed;
    CheckTimer.Start();
}
```

And this is my CheckTimer_Elapsed method:

```
void CheckTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("FirstText");
    Image IMG = new Image();
    MessageBox.Show("SecondText");
}
```

Why it is loading only a first MessageBox window? But, if it would be function that is called not by a Timer all is OK.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SomeFunc();
}
void SomeFunc()
{
    MessageBox.Show("FirstText");
    Image IMG = new Image();
    MessageBox.Show("SecondText");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a threading problem.

If I recall the event that is getting called from the timer is on a new thread. You are trying to do UI work which is not on the UI thread  (which is not allowed).  Couple of solutions to this, the simplest of which is to use a DispatcherTimer instead of a Timer. You can find it in System.Windows.Threading;

The Event that gets called from the DispatcherTimer is on the UI thread

Hope this helps